# =: This is not an identifier

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh

I am trying to set an environment in a KornShell (ksh) scipt using

```
 export DB_URL = jdbc@xyz.com
```

But I am getting  `=: This is not an identifier`

Please assist.

Answer (score 10):

Don't put spaces between the variable name, equal sign and its value.

```
export THIS=that
```

Or

```
THIS=that; export THIS
```